# android:exported="false" in a broadcast receiver with intent-filter declared

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to declare a broadcast receiver which can listen to system broadcasts like `PACKAGE_ADDED`, `PACKAGE_REPLACED`, for e.g.

```
 <receiver
    android:name="com.sample.cli.xyz.XyzReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If I keep `exported="true"` here, any app can send the broadcast and it can be a security issue. As per Android documentation if we have even 1 intent-filter in receiver tag then, default value of exported is considered "true".

My question is if I explicitly declare this attribute as "false" (`android:exported="false"`), along with intent-filters, will it make it more secure and make it accessible only by system and not other apps?

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element#exported

Comment: I read the documentation before posting the question here. There is no mention of the combination I have asked here. My question is specific to, what will the behaviour when I have intent-filter as well as exported is set to "false".

Answer (score 5):

Tried the combination (exported="false" along with intent-filter declared in receiver) asked in question, in a sample app and found that receiver can still listen to system events like PACKAGE_ADDED, PACKAGE_REMOVED etc.